# Surround a string with 2 chars in C

Tags: c, string, append, strcat

I have an array of strings that has been read from a file.
At some point i need to take one element out, add * before and * after and put it back to the same array.

So far I've managed to add one asterisk at the end with `strcat`. And it is printing it out correctly.
Now, how do I add the one at the beginning?

```
//malloc for the array has been done when read from file
char **array;
int arraySize;
for (i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
  if (some_condition){
    //Add * chars
    array[i]=strcat(array[i],"*");
    printf("Element %s was marked",array[i]);
  }
 //prints for example *foo*
 }
```

Sorry if the question is completely stupid and the answer might be obvious. Thanks for any possible answers in advance!

**UPD**: array malloc function

```
void readd(FILE *file){
  size=0; /*local size */
  char line[BUFSIZ]; /* Local array for a single word read */

  while ((fgets(line,sizeof(line),file))!=NULL){
    /* trim newline char */
    if (line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';

    array=(char**)realloc(array,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));
    array[size++]=strdup(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to alter the original string `array[i]`, or can you replace it with a new one that starts and ends with `*`?  How were the original `array[i]` strings allocated: malloc?  As character constants?  As char arrays on the stack?

Comment: Show us how you malloced the memory and read the string in originally. The most efficient answer will change that code, too.

Comment: @AdamLiss It would be preferable to use the same array. Please seee the OP for memory allocation.

Comment: side note: realloc at each line read is not efficient; prealloc N "slots" and when you fill all them, 2N and so on...

Comment: @ShinTakezou I chose such way because the size of an input file is unknown. So i need to dynamically reallocate memory as I read from the file.

Comment: it depends on the purpose of the code, but in general it is better to minimize malloc/realloc; the suggested way works fine for unknown size; the difference is that, instead of realloc from N to N+1, you realloc from N to N+N, and for the next N lines you don't need to realloc. At the end, you could waste a little bit of room, but that is not a problem (unless N is chosen to be too big) — anyway, it was just a side note OT with respect to your question

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i'm still a beginner. I will make a note of that and will have a closer look once the program will be near it's completition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original `array[i]` elements have enough room for the additional characters:

```
int len = strlen(array[i]);
memmove(array[i] + 1, array[i], len); // memmove() allows overlap btwn src & dest
array[i][0] = '*';
array[i][len+2] = '\0';
array[i][len+1] = '*'
```

---

**Edit:** Since you've updated your question, I'll update my answer.  :-)

First, be advised that it's dangerous to use `realloc()` like this:

```
array=(char**)realloc(array,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));
```

If the `realloc()` fails, then `array` is reassigned to `NULL` and the original pointer is lost, orphaning the memory that had been allocated to it.  This is safer:

```
char **tmp = realloc(array,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));
if (tmp == NULL) {
 // Out of memory error
}
array = tmp;
```

Of course, if you'll be doing this often, you might as well keep track of the current size and allocate room for another hundred or thousand elements at a time.

Since the individual strings are allocated with `strdup()` you have two options:

- Allocate an extra 2 characters for each, in case you need to add the asterisks.  This isn't unreasonable unless there are millions of strings, or the system is memory-constrained.
- Reallocate each string before adding the asterisks, using code like the snippets above.

Comment: Thank you for you reply and your advice. Being a beginner it takes me a little while to understand all the memory allocation/reallocation. But I promise i'll look into your advice :) Only few words in the array are going to be marked, so I suppose extra 2 chars could be allocated. Because there will be only few of those marked words I think reallocating each string beforehand would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Yes, pointers and memory management are common beginner's stumbling blocks, and even experienced programmers sometimes get them wrong.  Taking the time to understand them well is a very worthwhile investment.

Comment: I did as you suggested and with very few changes to suit my program it worked perfect. Many thanks for your advices! :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to go with doing a double strcat.

However, have you thought about memory management for this kind of thing? How are your string saved in memory?

On this line, you lose the pointer to the original string:

```
array[i]=strcat(array[i],"*");
```

Do you have another reference to the original pointer? Maybe you want to save it first, then reallocate with the same length + 2 characters, then put the first *, copy the string, put the last * and delete the original pointer.

Comment: strcat returns ptr to the resulting "string" dest, so the pointer shouldn't be lost. +1 for realloc, though time consuming, it makes it safe... but I would suggest to malloc the strings preemptively with a +2 to hold enough room for a probable double `*`

Comment: @ShinTakezou Right, thanks for noticing that the pointer is not lost. I was thinking about the reallocation and I thought I should mention potential memory management issues. Obviously I wrote a little too quickly.

Comment: Doing a double strcat indeed would be great. But strcat second argument only accepts `const char *` so i can't use my `array[i]` there...i think. Sorry, i'm not quite understanding what you mean by loosing a pointer.

Comment: @AlexMarch - const char* means that the function pledges not to change the characters int he array, does not mean the array contents must be unchangeable outside the function as well

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

You could copy every character in `array[i]` one position to the right (to a higher index) starting from the back and going towards the beginning, then replace the first character with the '*'.

This assumes that you have enough space to hold the two extra stars.

If not, you have two choices

- declare/allocate the original space large enough (at least two larger) or
- `malloc` a big enough area then copy the string starting from index 1 and place the stars at the appropriate position (index 0 and index `strlen(array[i])+1`.  Don't forget to re-assign the pointer in `array[i]` to the malloc'd area afterwards.